# error while decoding MB 171, 1, bytestream -27

Tags: python, stream, camera, computer-vision, rtsp

I have an app in which I read two RTSP streams from a hikvision camera and I do things with. There are two streams because it is a thermal camera and it has two streams, a normal stream and a thermal stream.
This is how I read the streams:

```
import cv2
normal_path = "rtsp://adress@192.168.1.120/Streaming/channels/102"
thermal_path = "rtsp://adress@192.168.1.120/Streaming/channels/201"
normal_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(normal_path)
thermal_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(thermal_path)
while True:
    try:
        ret,thermal_frame = thermal_capture.read(0)
        ret1,normal_frame = normal_capture.read(0)
        #do a lot of things
    except:
        continue

normal_capture.release()
thermal_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is that, after a while, for example, after 5 hours in which the app worked fine, it recives an error like this:

```
[h264 @ 0x2ac51c0] error while decoding MB 17 1, bytestream -27
```

Any idea why is this happening? Do you know why this error goes over the try and except ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with a single stream, although I was encountering it much sooner (a small number of minutes into the stream). I handle it by checking if `ret` is not `True`
and if so, rebuilding the stream.

```py
import cv2
thermal_path = "rtsp://adress@192.168.1.120/Streaming/channels/201"
thermal_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(thermal_path)
while True:

    ret, thermal_frame = thermal_capture.read(0)
    if not ret:
        thermal_capture.release()
        thermal_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(thermal_path)
        print('Found error; rebuilding stream')

    #do a lot of things

thermal_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```